# using third part modules in IBM quantum experience

Tags: python, quantum-computing

is there something i can do to use NumPy in IBM quantum experience? I have searched on google but i couldn't find anything. I thought about coping the source code, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy is one of the pre-installed packages (it's a pre-requisite for Qiskit, for one thing). You should be able to just do `import numpy` from your Jupyter notebook.